# class MarketingBusinessDetailView(generic.DetailView): syntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

from myapp import views 
File "C:\Users\User\job\mysite\myvenv\myproject\myapp\views.py", line 151

```
class MarketingBusinessDetailView(generic.DetailView):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

At models.py,

```
class MarketingBusiness(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter a brief description of the Marketing business.")


         def __str__(self):
                return self.title

          def get_absolute_url(self):
                 return reverse('myapp:marketingbusiness-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

And it's working perfectly in my admin.

At myapp urls.py,

```
 from myapp import views

 app_name = 'myapp'

 urlpatterns = [
       path('marketingbusinesses/', views.MarketingBusinessListView.as_view(), name='marketingbusiness'),
        path('marketingbusiness/<int:pk>/', views.MarketingBusinessDetailView.as_view(), name='marketingbusiness-detail'),
```

At views.py,

```
 from django.shortcuts import render 
  from django.views import View
  from django.views import generic 
  from myapp.models import MarketingBusiness 

 class MarketingBusinessDetailView(generic.DetailView):
         model = MarketingBusiness 

          def marketingbusiness_detail(request, pk):
                 marketingbusiness_id = get_object_or_404(MarketingBusiness, pk=pk)
                  return render(
                         request, 
                         'myapp/marketingbusiness-detail.html', context={'marketingbusiness_id':marketingbusiness}
                  )
```

How could I resolve this error, please?...

Comment: So what's on around line 151?

Comment: class MarketingBusinessDetailView(generic.DetailView):

Comment: yeah but that line is not the culprit so what's before and after it?

Comment: This is the response of the command prompt.

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\job\mysite\myvenv\myproject\myproject\urls.py", line 25, in (module) from myapp import views File "C:\Users\User\job\mysite\myvenv\myproject\myapp\views.py", line 151 class MarketingBusinessDetailView(generic.DetailView):  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I added views.py now in the question. Can you help, please?

Comment: I added views.py in the question. Can you help, please?...

Comment: you sure that's like 151?

Comment: Yes,  that's line 151

Comment: Can repetition of code in same app view caused this error but they are not of same model,  variable, function and template name(i.e they are of same step) ?...

Comment: it wouldn't give you syntax error. i would post the full traceback

Comment: Thank you, Dan-klasson. It's working now.

Comment: How do i vote for this?...

Comment: Well normally in this type of situation I would post an answer for you to upvote and accept. But I don't know what your problem and solution was. If I were you, I would post the answer myself. That helps other people who might stumble across your question in the future